# Como salvar arquivos php com caracteres utf8?

Tags: php, utf-8

Quando nomeio um arquivo php com caracteres utf8, por exemplo 'ççáá.php' o servidor local não abre o arquivo.

Eu realmente preciso de nomes utf8 para nomear estes arquivos, **mas é possível fazer algum tipo de conversão**. Ou seja pegar um nome **utf8**, converter ele para um nome de arquivo que o servidor reconheça e salvar o arquivo com o nome convertido. Após isso pegar o nome convertido e transforma-lo em utf8 para utilizar no código. **Ou seja o processo precisa ser reversível**.

*Qual a função ou algoritmo para realizar esta tarefa?*

**Obs:** Tentei utilizar **utf8_encode()/utf8_decode()** mas as duas geram nomes de arquivo que o servidor local também não reconhece.

Comment: Pegar `ççáá.php` e converter para ccaa.php é facil. Veja https://ideone.com/FMQ3DK porém pegar o nome convertido e transforma-lo em utf8 é complicado. Como saber se o nome era `ccáá.php` ou `ççaa.php` ou `ççáá.php` ou .......

Comment: Tive que remodelar o sistema para excluir a segunda necessidade. Agora só preciso converter ççáá em ccaa, o link que você postou cobre a necessidade. Obrigado.

Comment: Já que excluiu a segunda necessidade, vou postar o código do link como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

> Já que só precisa converter ççáá em ccaa, segundo seu comentário, vou postar o código do link aqui

Uma implementação segura de substituição de caracteres acentuados pode ser realizada com a função [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php) chamada com apenas dois argumentos. `strtr( $nomeArquivo, $indesejado_array );`

```
$nomeArquivo = "ççáá.php";
$indesejado_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                            'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                            'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                            'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                            'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );

$nomeArquivo = strtr( $nomeArquivo, $indesejado_array );
```

exemplo rodando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/FMQ3DK)